# Return statement inside using statemtn cause error "Not all code path return value"

Tags: c#, return, using

This code is look fine for me, I suppose nothing wrong to use return statement inside using statement, but compiler said that not all code path return value. How should I fix this to be able return string result?

```
public static string CallWebService(string an, string xmlcommand)
        {
            //test
            //Dim _url = "http://testapi.interface-xml.com/appservices/ws/FrontendService"
            //live
            dynamic _url = "http://212.170.239.18/appservices/ws/FrontendService";
            try
            {
                string soapResult = null;
                XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(xmlcommand);
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, an);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
                IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
                asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                {
                    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(bs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(gz))
                            {
                                if (an == "HotelValuedAvailRQ")
                                {
                                    soapResult = rd.ReadLine();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                                return soapResult; //This is what I want to return
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(2000);
                s.AppendFormat("<b>К сожалению превышено время ожидания.</b>: {0} <br /><b>Источник</b>: {1}<br /><a href='javascript:history.back();'>Вернуться</a>", ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
                HttpContext.Current.Session["bug"] = s.ToString();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../errors/error.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  If the code throws an error, it may not get to the return statement, hence nothing will be returned.  Move the return statement to after the catch block.

Comment: Side note - You can avoid the heavy nesting by simply stating the `using` statements one after the other and only opening the brackets after the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't your `using` statement, but your `try` statement: excecution **could** abort anywhere in your `try` block before it gets to `return`, then code would enter your `catch(TimeoutException ex)` handler, but you don't have a `return` statement in there.

I see your code seems to be part of a web-application, however this looks like a "backend" method that returns content to a consuming method. You should not write to `Response` from here, instead return `null` or don't catch the exception and instead let the caller of your `CallWebService` be responsible for displaying an error message.

I see you're making a few other mistakes like using `dynamic` instead of `String`, this is how I would write your code:

```
public static string CallWebService(string an, string xmlcommand)
{
    String url = @"http://212.170.239.18/appservices/ws/FrontendService";
    try
    {
        String soapResult = null;
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(xmlcommand);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, an);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
        using(HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (Stream s = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(gz))
        {
            if (an == "HotelValuedAvailRQ")
            {
                soapResult = rd.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return soapResult;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    { 
        return null;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- You were using `dynamic` incorrectly. `dynamic` is not equivalent to VB's `Dim` statement.
- You were using the async methods of `HttpWebRequest` but blocking, so you might as well just use the blocking methods (`GetResponse`)
- You shouldn't wrap the Response's stream in a `BufferedStream`, just use it directly.
- You can combine `using` blocks together.
- You don't need to perform GZip decompression yourself, `HttpWebResponse` does this automatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx
- I don't think it's a good idea to control the ASP.NET HTTP response from a backend method as it leaves the consumer of `CallWebService` in an unknown state, instead the consumer should check to see if `CallWebService` returns null and if so, render the error message.

Note that in both `catch` blocks, you might want to log the exceptions because their details are being swallowed. They may indicate a downed service or other problem.

Comment: Thanks. Really good update of my old piece of VB.NET code translated to C#.

Comment: The only problem is here using(HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse()) - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.WebResponse' to 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @andrey.shedko sorry, that's a bug. Yes, you need to perform an explicit casting to `HttpWebResponse`. It's a design-flaw in the .NET Framework.